# How to access Laravel Nova from the root?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I want to be able to access Laravel Nova from the root, i.e. from `example.com` and not `example.com/nova`.

I have tried changing the path setting in `config/nova.php` to `'/'`. Going to `example.com` then redirects to `example.com/login` which looks right, but it throws the following error:

> No hint path defined for [nova].

I'm new to Laravel but some searching suggests this is to do with the FileViewFinder but I don't know how to resolve this. The closest answer I found suggested adding `Laravel/Nova/Http/Middleware/ServeNova` to the list of providers in `config/app.php` but this throws a new error (`Call to undefined method Laravel\Nova\Http\Middleware\ServeNova::isDeferred()`).

Is it possible to serve Nova from the root and if so, how?

Comment: When do you get the error `No hint path defined for` ? When login page loads or when you trying to login?

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam The error is displayed when the page loads. I don't have any opportunity to log in etc.

Answer (score 5):

Just change the 'path' to '/' in config/nova.php should work:

```
 'path' => '/',
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the default route '/' in routes/web.php though.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can do a redirect like this in your web.php file

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect(config('nova.path')); 
});
```